# Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE type mismatch error

Tags: android, kotlin, clipboard

I am newbie for Kotlin. I tried to add an option near to "cut","copy".. options. And it will paste any random number on any app. But when i try this :

```
var clipboard = getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE) as ClipboardManager
// Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE type mismatch error and no value passed for parameter 'p1' error
```

Here is my codes:

```
import android.content.ClipData
import android.content.ClipboardManager
import android.content.Context
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.MenuInflater
import android.view.MenuItem
import androidx.appcompat.view.ActionMode
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.getSystemService
import java.util.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        }
    }

    class CustomActionModeCallback : ActionMode.Callback {

        override fun onCreateActionMode(mode: ActionMode?, menu: Menu?): Boolean {
            val inflater: MenuInflater = mode!!.menuInflater
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_custom_action_mode, menu)
            return true
        }

        override fun onPrepareActionMode(mode: ActionMode?, menu: Menu?): Boolean {
            return false
        }

        override fun onActionItemClicked(mode: ActionMode?, item: MenuItem?): Boolean {
            when (item!!.itemId) {
                R.id.menu_item_custom -> {
                   
                    var clipboard = getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE) as ClipboardManager
                    var randomNumber = "123123"
                    var clip = ClipData.newPlainText("Random Number", randomNumber)
                    clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip)
                    mode!!.finish()
                    return true
                }
            }
            return false
        }
```

What i tried : Copy Clipboard

What happened :
Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE type mismatch error and no value passed for parameter 'p1' error